# pynamodb amazon credential exception

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I am following the pynamodb documentation

```
class Thread(Model):
    class Meta:
        read_capacity_units = 1
        write_capacity_units = 1
        table_name = "Thread"
        region = 'us-west-1'
        host = "http://localhost:8888"

    forum_name = UnicodeAttribute(hash_key=True)
    subject = UnicodeAttribute(range_key=True)
    views = NumberAttribute(default=0)
    replies = NumberAttribute(default=0)
    answered = NumberAttribute(default=0)
    tags = UnicodeSetAttribute()
    last_post_datetime = UTCDateTimeAttribute(null=True)

# Delete the table
# print(Thread.delete_table())

# Create the table
if not Thread.exists():
    Thread.create_table(wait=True)
```

When i run above code it gives error:

```
DEBUG:pynamodb.connection.base:Calling DescribeTable with arguments {'TableName': 'Thread'}
```

and raises exception:

```
raise TableError("Unable to describe table: {0}".format(e), e)
```

TableError: Unable to describe table: Unable to locate credentials

How to provide the pynamodb aws_secret_key_id and aws_access key. I am running the example on local computer using dynamodb local.

How I provide the credential information in pynamodb. I did set environment variables of the aws_secret_key_id and aws_access_key but still credential exeception

Is there any way to provide the aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key as a parameter in the pynamodb like bellow example:-

this code working and create the database but i want use the pynamodb library

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb',
                          region_name='us-west-2',
                          aws_access_key_id="access key",
                          aws_secret_access_key="secret acess key",
                          endpoint_url="http://localhost:8888")
```

Answer (score 3):

In Meta class, include

```
aws_access_key_id = "anything"
aws_secret_access_key = "fake"
```

You can give any fake secret access key and access key.

Answer (score 1):

create a file ~/.aws/credentials and enter

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = 'foo'
aws_secret_access_key = 'bar
```

or better still

[Unable to locate credentials](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/915#issuecomment-56250077)

Answer (score 1):

I was in similar problem and got the same exception

the solution was to configure aws by terminal with `aws configure`

and then see the configuration by `aws configure list`

but in my case I had another problem (I am using Ubuntu), that when I used `aws configure list` I found that configuration was not set, but when I used `sudo aws configure list' it works.

so I went to '~/.aws' 
and changed the permissions of 'credentials' file with command

`sudo chmod +r credentials`

then my command for creating dynamodb and making tests worked.